# Lite/Embedded alternatives to SQLite (in Android)?

Tags: android, sqlite, derby, embedded-database

Are there any alternatives to SQLite DB? I mean any kind of light/embedded SQL DBs like Derby or Hypersonic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [H2 database engine supports Android](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#android).

Answer (score 0):

No what you are asking for is not present.