# Download link for SQLite for Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite

I did not find any downloads of SQLite for Android or iOS on http://www.sqlite.org/download.html, though I did find a binary download for Windows Phone 8.

- Where can I download SQLite for Android and iOS platforms?
- Also, are there any other databases I can use for local work on Android and iOS devices?

Comment: http://sqlite-manager.softpedia.com/          Here is the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - Where can I download SQLite for Android and iOS platforms?

SQLite support is built-in in both these platforms. Start using it right away. Refer [Using Databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) in Android and [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) in iOS.

> - Also, are there any other databases I can use for local work on Android and iOS devices?

There are several (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7754225/1321873) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/417917/1321873)), but why do you need anything else when SQLite is supported natively.

Answer (score 0):

Where can I download SQLite for Android?
please refer below link.
platforms?http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

you can store the values in shared preferences locally, sqlite is only database available to
store value in database